# How to test class constructor in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Let's say I have a class like following:

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

How can I test through Jest that constructor was initialized the right way? Say... `this.a = a` and `this.b = b` and not vice versa?

I know that I can execute `toBeCalledWith` but that won't let me check the constructor's logic. I was also thinking about making `mockImplementation` but in this case it seems pointless as I will rewrite the logic, or I may not be aware of all the nuances of creating mocks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just create an instance of the object and check it directly. Since it sets them on `this`, they are essentially public values:

```
it('works', () => {
  const obj = new SomeClass(1, 2);
  expect(obj.a).toBe(1);
  expect(obj.b).toBe(2);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply check the instance properties after initializing the class. Basicly the same as you can test the side effects of any function.

```
const a = Symbol();
const b = Symbol();    
const classInstance = new SomeClass(a, b);
expect(classInstance.a).toBe(a);
expect(classInstance.b).toBe(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you know where the class is coming from you can do something like this:

```js
jest.mock('path/to/module');
...
it('should work', () => {
  const a = Symbol();
  const b = Symbol();
  expect(SomeClass).toBeCalledWith(a, b);
});
```