# Static Properties in mocked Classes are undefined? (Jest)

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, mocking

I am currently trying to Mock a class that has a static property..

```
jest.mock("../../src/logger/index");
import { Logger } from "../../src/logger/index";

// ..

const LoggerMock = Logger as jest.MockedClass<typeof Logger>;

expect(LoggerMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(Logger.level.WARN);

// ..
```

And after mocking the Class the static property `level` does return undefined..
-> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'WARN' of undefined`

-> Does anybody know how to **mock a class** with a **static property** properly?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you expect class to be called? If you expect some function to be called with `Logger.level.WARN`, you should pass function reference into `expect`

Answer (score 0):

#### First of all: Jest `expect` only works inside `it`/`test` blocks

Secondly, I see you expect `Logger` to be called, but `Logger` is a class. You should expect a **function** to be called **with arguments**.

For example:

```
// Logger.ts
export class Logger {
  static WARN() {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

```
// Logger.spec.ts
import { Logger } from './Logger';

jest.mock('./logger');

const LoggerMock = Logger as jest.MockedClass<typeof Logger>;

it.only('should work', () => {
  LoggerMock.WARN();

  expect(LoggerMock.WARN).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
});
```

This setup works fine for me

Comment: you are right.. with the `// ..` I mean that there is code missing.. 
I only wanted to point on the important parts.. 

And `level` is a static property in Logger that holds an object with WARN, ERROR, .. 
to get a visual imagination of the level.. 

I think to get a better understanding you can take a look into the actual tests
https://github.com/agile-ts/agile/blob/tests/rewrite-tests/packages/core/tests/new/agile.test.ts

And I don't want to check if a Function got called I want to know if the constructor got called -> class got instantiated by Agile

Comment: There are debates about testing constructors and private methods, I prefer to not test them. But if you need to, you should consider reading about [blackbox testing](https://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/black-box-testing/#:~:text=BLACK%20BOX%20TESTING%2C%20also%20known,%2Dfunctional%2C%20though%20usually%20functional.). You should only check outcomes of calling some function. So your takeaway here is: use constructor => check if all public properties are correct, do not test that constructor is called with arguments. [Jest: testing constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49886337/13104050)

Comment: yeah I am doing that as an alternative.. thanks for your help